# Guidewire Studio: how activate git UI tools?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

May I know how we can check version control file history in Studio version 8.0. Suppose if we want to see who and what changes had been made as part of one file. I have checked Version control under setting tab. But not sure how to enable?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you would do in any other project with Intellij. As long as your project is mapped correctly and the .git file is pointing properly, right click the file within studio >> Git >> Show History. You can then select in Git Log and do various other operations.